# Why are script properties lost when passing pscustomobject to start-job script block?

Tags: powershell, start-job, pscustomobject

On windows XP x64 (and I assume win2k3) powershell 2.0, passing an arraylist of pscustomobjects to start-job as argumentlist parameter passes the object in but scriptproperties just disappear from the object (confirmed by get-member). Note properties of the pscustomobject do return just fine

Anyone know why? and/or have a solution for a work around?

$dbs is arraylist with pscustomobjects that have various noteproperties and scriptproperties.

All of the script properties disappear once passed into start-job, while note properties work just fine.

**Below executed outside of start-job**

```
$dbs | get-member
```

**returns**

```
ConnectionString NoteProperty   System.String ConnectionString=server=...
DbType           NoteProperty   System.String DbType=Staging                                                                                   
 CreateBackup     ScriptMethod   System.Object CreateBackup ();                                                                                  
GetBackup        ScriptMethod   System.Object GetBackup();
```

...
**while**

```
start-job -name $server -argumentlist $dbs,$server -scriptblock {
    param($dbs, $server)
 $dbs | get-member
 }
```

**Returns**

```
bool Equals(System.Object obj) 
int GetHashCode() 
type GetType() 
string ToString() 
System.String ConnectionString=server=...
System.String DbType=Staging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Custom PowerShell Host and Converting PSObject back to base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330659/custom-powershell-host-and-converting-psobject-back-to-base-type) I answered some time ago. It is the same case.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have realized it was using PS remoting under the hood and seen the presence of flattened properties as indication of serialization. Its a bit of a bummer given the utility methods on the object will have to be replicated in the script block in order to use them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Background jobs use remoting.  Remoting serializes the objects and then sends them to the target runspace, where they are de-serialized.  When an object is serialized, object methods are not included in the serialized object.